# XML error parsing attribute name

Tags: xml, parsing

I am attempting to make a card game conversion for a popular card game. I am attempting to make an xml file with all card data. I have attempted many things but still come up with the same error when attempting to run with any browser:

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 8 at column 10: error parsing attribute name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Gorgona 500

Here is the code starting from line 6 to 14.

```
<cardId ="01">
<type name = "Boss">
  <title>Gorgona</title>
  <xp>500 XP</xp>
  <treasureIcon>Treasure</treasureIcon>
  <heading>Queen of Medusia</heading>
  <levelUp>Level Up: Choose a Hero in town. Immediately kill that Hero and place it face-down in your scorekeeping area.</levelUp>
  </type>
</cardId>
```

Here is the code in its entirety:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<BossCards>

<Card Id="01">
  <Type Name="Boss">
    <Title>Gorgona</Title>
    <Xp>500 XP</Xp>
    <TreasureIcon>Treasure</TreasureIcon>
    <Heading>Queen of Medusia</Heading>
    <LevelUp>Level Up: Choose a Hero in town. Immediately kill that Hero and place it face-down in your scorekeeping area.</LevelUp>
  </Type>
</Card>

<card Id ="02">
  <title>Seducia</title>
  <xp>600 XP</xp>
  <treasureIcon>Magic</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Boss">
  <heading>Sorceress of Sexiness</heading>
  <levelUp>Level Up: You may search through town or the Hero decks, choose one Hero, and put it at the entrance to your dungeon.</levelUp>
</card>

<card>
  <title>Draculord</title>
  <xp>900 XP</xp>
  <cardId = "03">
  <treasureIcon>Ankh</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Boss">
  <heading>Hypnotic Vampire</heading>
  <levelUp>Level Up: Target opponent reveals his or her hand to you. Take one card and put it into your hand.</levelUp>
</card>

<card>
  <title>Xyzax</title>
  <xp>750 XP</xp>
  <cardId = "04">
  <treasureIcon>Ankh</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Boss">
  <heading>Progenitor Lich</heading>
  <levelUp>Level Up: Choose two cards from the discard pile and put them into your hand.</levelUp>
</card>

<card>
  <title>Robobo</title>
  <xp>400 XP</xp>
  <cardId = "05">
  <treasureIcon>Sword</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Boss">
  <heading>Angry Golem</heading>
  <levelUp>Level Up: Each opponent must choose and destroy one Room in his or her dungeon.</levelUp>
</card>

<card>
  <title>Cerebellus</title>
  <xp>650 XP</xp>
  <cardId = "06">
  <treasureIcon>Magic</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Boss">
  <heading>Father Brain</heading>
  <levelUp>Level Up: You may draw there Spell cards, then discard a Spell card.</levelUp>
</card>

<card>
  <title>Cleopatra</title>
  <xp>850 XP</xp>
  <cardId = "07">
  <treasureIcon>Thief</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Boss">
  <heading>Mother of Mummies</heading>
  <levelUp>Level Up: Search the Room deck or discard pile for an Advanced Trap Room. You may immediately build the Room (over a Room with a matching treasure type).</levelUp>
</card>

<card>
  <title>King Croak</title>
  <xp>800 XP</xp>
  <cardId = "08">
  <treasureIcon>Fighter</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Boss">
  <heading>Sultan of the Sewers</heading>
  <levelUp><b>Level Up:</b> Search the Room deck or discard pile for an Advanced Monster Room. You may immediately build the Room (over a Room with a matching treasure type).</levelUp>
</card>

</BossCards>

<card>
  <title>Xyzax</title>
  <xp>750 XP</xp>
  <cardId = "04">
  <treasureIcon>Ankh</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Boss">
  <heading>Progenitor Lich</heading>
  <levelUp>Level Up: Choose two cards from the discard pile and put them into your hand.</levelUp>
</card>

<card>
  <title>Robobo</title>
  <xp>400 XP</xp>
  <cardId = "05">
  <treasureIcon>Sword</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Boss">
  <heading>Angry Golem</heading>
  <levelUp>Level Up: Each opponent must choose and destroy one Room in his or her dungeon.</levelUp>
</card>

<card>
  <title>Cerebellus</title>
  <xp>650 XP</xp>
  <cardId = "06">
  <treasureIcon>Magic</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Boss">
  <heading>Father Brain</heading>
  <levelUp>Level Up: You may draw there Spell cards, then discard a Spell card.</levelUp>
</card>

<card>
  <title>Cleopatra</title>
  <xp>850 XP</xp>
  <cardId = "07">
  <treasureIcon>Thief</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Boss">
  <heading>Mother of Mummies</heading>
  <levelUp>Level Up: Search the Room deck or discard pile for an Advanced Trap Room. You may immediately build the Room (over a Room with a matching treasure type).</levelUp>
</card>

<card>
  <title>King Croak</title>
  <xp>800 XP</xp>
  <cardId = "08">
  <treasureIcon>Fighter</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Boss">
  <heading>Sultan of the Sewers</heading>
  <levelUp><b>Level Up:</b> Search the Room deck or discard pile for an Advanced Monster Room. You may immediately build the Room (over a Room with a matching treasure type).</levelUp>
</card>

</BossCards>

<SpellCards>

<card>
  <cardId = "010">
  <title>Teleportation</title>
  <howManyInDeck>2</howManyInDeck>
  <type name = "Spell">
  <phaseIcon>Build</phaseIcon>
  <heading>Teleportation</heading>
  <ability>Send a Hero in your dungeon back to the first Room of your dungeon.</ability>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "011">
  <title>Assassin</title>
  <howManyInDeck>3</howManyInDeck>
  <type name = "Spell">
  <phaseIcon>Build</phaseIcon>
  <heading>Assassin</heading>
  <ability>Choose a Hero in an opponent's dungeon. Give that Hero +3 HPs until end of turn.</ability>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "012">
  <title>Fear</title>
  <howManyInDeck>2</howManyInDeck>
  <type name = "Spell">
  <phaseIcon>Build</phaseIcon>
  <heading>Fear</heading>
  <ability>Choose a Hero in any dungeon and send it back to town.</ability>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "013">
  <title>Freeze</title>
  <howManyInDeck>4</howManyInDeck>
  <type name = "Spell">
  <phaseIcon>Both</phaseIcon>
  <heading>Freeze</heading>
  <ability>Choose and deactivate one Room in any dungeon<i>(It has no damage, treasure, or abilities until end of turn).</i></ability>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "014">
  <title>Trepidation</title>
  <type name = "Spell">
  <phaseIcon>Adventure</phaseIcon>
  <heading>Trepidation</heading>
  <ability>Choose a player with at least two more Souls than you. No Hero enters that player's dungeon this turn.<i>(Any Heroes remain at the entrance to that dungeon).</i></ability>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "015">
  <title>Cave-In</title>
  <howManyInDeck>2</howManyInDeck>
  <type name = "Spell">
  <phaseIcon>Adventure</phaseIcon>
  <heading>Cave-In</heading>
  <ability>Destroy a Room in your dungeon. Kill any Hero in that Room.</ability>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "016">
  <title>Giant Size</title>
  <howManyInDeck>2</howManyInDeck>
  <type name = "Spell">
  <phaseIcon>Adventure</phaseIcon>
  <heading>Fear</heading>
  <ability>Give on Monster Room +3 damage until end of turn.</ability>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "017">
  <title>Motivation</title>
  <howManyInDeck>2</howManyInDeck>
  <type name = "Spell">
  <phaseIcon>Build</phaseIcon>
  <heading>Motivation</heading>
  <ability>If you have fewer Rooms that an opponent, you may build an extra Room this turn. <i>(You must declare this before any Rooms are revealed).</i></ability>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "018">
  <title>Princess in Peril</title>
  <howManyInDeck>2</howManyInDeck>
  <type name = "Spell">
  <phaseIcon>Build</phaseIcon>
  <heading>Princess in Peril</heading>
  <ability>Choose on Hero in town. Place it at the entrance to your dungeon.</ability>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "019">
  <title>Kobold Strike</title>
  <type name = "Spell">
  <phaseIcon>Build</phaseIcon>
  <heading>Kobold Strike</heading>
  <ability>No Rooms can be built this turn. Any face-down Room is returned to its owner's hand.</ability>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "020">
  <title>Zombie Attack</title>
  <howManyInDeck>2</howManyInDeck>
  <type name = "Spell">
  <phaseIcon>Build</phaseIcon>
  <heading>Zombie Attack</heading>
  <ability>Choose a dead Hero in an opponent's scorekeeping area. Send it back to the entrance of that player's dungeon. Until end of turn it has +2 HPs.</ability>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "021">
  <title>Jeopardy</title>
  <howManyInDeck>2</howManyInDeck>
  <type name = "Spell">
  <phaseIcon>Both</phaseIcon>
  <heading>Jeopardy</heading>
  <ability>All players must discard their hands, then draw one Spell card and two Room cards.</ability>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "022">
  <title>Counterspell</title>
  <howManyInDeck>2</howManyInDeck>
  <type name = "Spell">
  <phaseIcon>Both</phaseIcon>
  <heading>Counterspell</heading>
  <ability>Choose a Spell card that has just been declared. Cancel the effects of that Spell card.<i>(The cancelled Spell card is sent to the discard pile).</i></ability>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "023">
  <title>Soul Harvest</title>
  <type name = "Spell">
  <phaseIcon>Both</phaseIcon>
  <heading>Soul Harvest</heading>
  <ability>Choose a face-down Hero in your scorekeeping area and remove it from the game. Draw two Spell cards.</ability>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "024">
  <title>Annihilator</title>
  <howManyInDeck>2</howManyInDeck>
  <type name = "Spell">
  <phaseIcon>Adventure</phaseIcon>
  <heading>Annihilator</heading>
  <ability>Give one Trap Room +3 damage until end of turn.</ability>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "025">
  <title>Exhaustion</title>
  <type name = "Spell">
  <phaseIcon>Adventure</phaseIcon>
  <heading>Exhaustion</heading>
  <ability>Deal X damage to one Hero in your dungeon, where X is equal to the number of Rooms in your dungeon.</ability>
</card>

</SpellCards>

<HeroCards>

<card>
  <cardId = "030">
  <title>Fighter</title>
  <numberofPlayers>4</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>2</soulValue>
  <health>4</health>
  <wounds>2</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Fighter</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Epic Hero">
  <heading>Epic Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Jarek, Squire to the Lion Knights:</b><br /> <i>As a squire, Jarek loved nothing more than stories and legends. He had no idea that he would someday become one.</i></flavorText>
 </card>

<card>
  <cardId = "031">
  <title>Mage</title>
  <numberofPlayers>4</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>4</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Fighter</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Brandork the Neverwrong</b><br /> <i>Schooled in seven flavors of magic, Brandork follows the teachings of Master Face, the Omniscient Celestial.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "032">
  <title>Fighter</title>
  <numberofPlayers>4</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>8</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Fighter</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Crystol and A'lan of Gerd</b><br /> <i>Bound by the unbreakable Ring of Gerd, these lovers became the most dangerous husband-wife team in the adventuring business.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "033">
  <title>Cleric</title>
  <numberofPlayers>3</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>6</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Cleric</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Charles the Young</b><br /> <i>Charles has his mother's permission to go adventuring, but he has to return before sundown.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "034">
  <title>Thief</title>
  <numberofPlayers>4</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>4</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Thief</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Lance Uppercut</b><br /> <i>With a bent blade and a clenched fist, he gathers shining treasures for the glory of the Keonish Empire.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "035">
  <title>Cleric</title>
  <numberofPlayers>4</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>4</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Cleric</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Pugi the Druidess</b><br /> <i>A defender of the wilderness, she wields the power of Nature. Flowers blossom in her footsteps, and life grows anew.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "036">
  <title>Cleric</title>
  <numberofPlayers>4</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>8</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Cleric</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Romero, the Indigo Friar</b><br /> <i>He is a dedicated man of the cloth who wants to see the world coated in blue. You might think he's depressed, but he's actually very, very happy.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "037">
  <title>Fighter</title>
  <numberofPlayers>3</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>6</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Fighter</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Samurai Tom</b><br /> <i>Not truly a samurai, this masterless ronin seeks honor and glory.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "038">
  <title>Thief</title>
  <numberofPlayers>2</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>6</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Thief</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Jesta the Rogue</b><br /> <i>"Okay, so you take the big guy on the left with the axe, you've got the two little ones on the right with swords, and I'll take this dangerous looking treasure chest with no lock over here..."</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "039">
  <title>Mage</title>
  <numberofPlayers>4</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>8</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Mage</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Koey, the Last Dragon Mage</b><br /> <i>The survivor of Drakonia vowed to save the world from Kirax's reign with the power bestowed to him buy the last emerald dragon.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "040">
  <title>Mage</title>
  <numberofPlayers>2</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>4</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Mage</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Tieg and the Magic Bubble</b><br /> <i>Armed with his trusty bubble, Tieg braves dangerous castles and dungeons in search of the musical instruments stolen from his people.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "041">
  <title>Mage</title>
  <numberofPlayers>3</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>6</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Mage</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Kalish Ninefingers</b><br /> <i>The worst thief ever, Kalish lost a finger and his freedom in one night. Taught magic in prison buy his sorcerous cellmate, he now kills evil with fire.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "042">
  <title>Thief</title>
  <numberofPlayers>3</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>6</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Thief</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Kins Klauski, Mad Conquistador</b><br /> <i>"It's Hard for me to think about death, how insects and worms will eat me... I never think about death, I haven't even properly started to live yet."</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "043">
  <title>Mage</title>
  <numberofPlayers>2</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>8</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Mage</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Dartteon, Elf Pyromancer</b><br /> <i>Some elves just want to watch the world burn.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "044">
  <title>Thief</title>
  <numberofPlayers>2</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>4</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Thief</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Joman Chimm, Cutpurse</b><br /> <i>From the twinkle in his eye, you might think he comes bearing gifts ...until you check your empty pockets.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "045">
  <title>Cleric</title>
  <numberofPlayers>2</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>8</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Cleric</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Delatorious, Angel of Light</b><br /> <i>Created by the Goddess of Light to defend Arcadia, this kid angel never misses a shot with his enchanted crossbow.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "046">
  <title>Mage</title>
  <numberofPlayers>2</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>6</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Mage</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Mitchell, the Judge</b><br /> <i>He has wandered the planes, hopelessly lost... ever since his wife, Nikki, sent him to the store for diamond dust sugar.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "047">
  <title>Cleric</title>
  <numberofPlayers>2</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>6</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Cleric</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Acacia, Warrior of Light</b><br /> <i>Acacia is a carefree soul who makes her own luck. A strong defender of good, she is undeterred by even the darkets dungeons.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "048">
  <title>Fighter</title>
  <numberofPlayers>2</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>8</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Fighter</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Johnny of the Evening Watch</b><br /> <i>A humble member of the Evening Watch, whose band o' brothers is sworn to forsake family, take the grey, and clear dungeons.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "049">
  <title>Fighter</title>
  <numberofPlayers>2</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>8</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Fighter</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Delatorious, Angel of Light</b><br /> <i>Created by the Goddess of Light to defend Arcadia, this kid angel never misses a shot with his enchanted crossbow.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "050">
  <title>The Fool</title>
  <numberofPlayers>2</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>2</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>The Fool</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>The Fool is lured to the dungeon of the player with the fewest souls.</b><br /> <i>(In the case of a tie, he waits in town until the tie is broken).</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "051">
  <title>Cleric</title>
  <numberofPlayers>2</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>4</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Cleric</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Nick the Masher</b><br /> <i>The young cleric was well-armed, and brave enough to take on the Dragon King himself. His credo: "I bash it with my mace."</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "052">
  <title>Thief</title>
  <numberofPlayers>2</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>8</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Thief</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Sir Digby Apple, Ace Detective</b><br /> <i>He battles to keep the coffers filling, to keep his partners preening and to send a needless message of power to all of the unwilling</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "053">
  <title>Fighter</title>
  <numberofPlayers>2</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>4</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Fighter</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Boden the Pantless</b><br /> <i>Boden's courage is matched only by his forgetfulness. The quest to find his misplaced armor continues!</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "054">
  <title>Fighter</title>
  <numberofPlayers>2</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>6</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Fighter</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Fire's Breath, Heroine of Arcadia</b><br /> <i>The scarlet-haired warrior woman known as Fire's Breath has pledged her deadly twin blades to the fight for liberty.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "055">
  <title>Thief</title>
  <numberofPlayers>4</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>1</soulValue>
  <health>8</health>
  <wounds>1</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Thief</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Ordinary Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Jerome, Kung Fu Monkey</b><br /> <i>A visitor from a distant land, this hyperactive monkey studied martial arts under the legendary Sifu Wang.</i></flavorText>
</card>

</HeroCards>

<EpicHeroCards>
<card>
  <cardId = "060">
  <title>Thief</title>
  <numberofPlayers>3</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>2</soulValue>
  <health>11</health>
  <wounds>2</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Thief</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Epic Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Blackbeard Jake</b><br /> <i>He hid all the treasure he won from insult swordfighting in a booby trap-filled cave on the coast of a town called Astoria.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "061">
  <title>Mage</title>
  <numberofPlayers>2</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>2</soulValue>
  <health>13</health>
  <wounds>2</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Mage</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Epic Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Terric Warhelm, Half-Elf Archmage</b><br /> <i>Weakened by an evil curse, this once mighty warrior donned the red robes and turned to magic. His spells are channelled through a magical helmet of untold power.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "062">
  <title>Fighter</title>
  <numberofPlayers>2</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>2</soulValue>
  <health>11</health>
  <wounds>2</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Fighter</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Epic Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Frankov, the Envoy</b><br /> <i>This brave warrior stands alone against the evil that rules the world.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "063">
  <title>Cleric</title>
  <numberofPlayers>2</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>2</soulValue>
  <health>11</health>
  <wounds>2</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Cleric</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Epic Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Katelyn, Angelic Healer</b><br /> <i>Among the most exalted defenders of righteousness, Katelyn is sometimes referred to as "altissima luce" -- highest light.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "064">
  <title>Thief</title>
  <numberofPlayers>2</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>2</soulValue>
  <health>13</health>
  <wounds>2</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Thief</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Epic Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Cecil Leoran, Master Factotum</b><br /> <i>The ultimate jack-of-all-trades, Cecil isn't above taking mercenary work to earn gold and glory. But his real goal has never changed: to find a way to return his betrothed Nevra, sealed into a rapier, to her original form.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "065">
  <title>Thief</title>
  <numberofPlayers>2</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>2</soulValue>
  <health>11</health>
  <wounds>2</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Thief</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Epic Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Hya, Legendary Shinobi</b><br /> <i>Arcadia's deadliest ninja, Hya abides by the proverb that revenge is a dish best served cold.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "066">
  <title>Thief</title>
  <numberofPlayers>3</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>2</soulValue>
  <health>11</health>
  <wounds>2</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Thief</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Epic Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Blackbeard Jake</b><br /> <i>He hid all the treasure he won from insult swordfighting in a booby trap-filled cave on the coast of a town called Astoria.</i></flavorText>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "060">
  <title>Thief</title>
  <numberofPlayers>3</numberofPlayers>
  <soulValue>2</soulValue>
  <health>11</health>
  <wounds>2</wounds>
  <treasureIcon>Thief</treasureIcon>
  <type name = "Hero">
  <heading>Epic Hero</heading>
  <flavorText><b>Blackbeard Jake</b><br /> <i>He hid all the treasure he won from insult swordfighting in a booby trap-filled cave on the coast of a town called Astoria.</i></flavorText>
</card>

</EpicHeroCards>

<RoomCards>

<card>
  <cardId = "090">
  <type name = "Advanced Monster">
  <title></title>
  <roomIcon></roomIcon>
  <howmanyicons></howmanyicons>
  <ability></ability>
  <damage></damage>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "110">
  <type name = "Advanced Trap">
  <title></title>
  <roomIcon></roomIcon>
  <howmanyicons></howmanyicons>
  <ability></ability>
  <damage></damage>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "150">
  <type name = "Monster">
  <title></title>
  <roomIcon></roomIcon>
  <howmanyicons></howmanyicons>
  <ability></ability>
  <damage></damage>
</card>

<card>
  <cardId = "180">
  <type name = "Trap">
  <title></title>
  <roomIcon></roomIcon>
  <howmanyicons></howmanyicons>
  <ability></ability>
  <damage></damage>
</card>

</RoomCards>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your error

```
 <cardId ="01">
```

Your root element should be `Card` with an attribute `Id`

Like so:

```
<Card Id="01">
  <Type Name="Boss">
    <Title>Gorgona</Title>
    <Xp>500 XP</Xp>
    <TreasureIcon>Treasure</TreasureIcon>
    <Heading>Queen of Medusia</Heading>
    <LevelUp>Level Up: Choose a Hero in town. Immediately kill that Hero and place it face-down in your scorekeeping area.</LevelUp>
  </Type>
</Card >
```

Take a look here :
[XML Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp)

Comment: I attempted to copy your code and paste it exactally. I am now getting this error: 

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 13 at column 7: expected '>'
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

This starts at line 5 and ends at 13

Comment: Can you show me your code ? how do you parse your xml

Comment: Code is far to many characters for me to paste. Here is just a snippet:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<BossCards>

<Card Id="01">
  <Type Name="Boss">
    <Title>Gorgona</Title>
    <Xp>500 XP</Xp>
    <TreasureIcon>Treasure</TreasureIcon>
    <Heading>Queen of Medusia</Heading>
    <LevelUp>Level Up: Choose a Hero in town. Immediately kill that Hero and place it face-down in your scorekeeping area.</LevelUp>
  </Type>
</Card>

</BossCards>

Comment: Modify your question ... :P

Comment: Its been added to the original post... mind you its is not finished as I did not wish to continue until I had this right. Sadly enough I did alot of work before I realized it was wrong. The beginning of the code has been changed with your recommendations so it has not all been converted yet.